# Meaning of 'reciprocate'

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I want to know its meaning in the context *glitter reciprocated in my bag* what does it mean here? Since in the mathematical terms , it meand the inverse. But here, it sounds a bit weird to me. Can't there be any other word used instead? 
P.s not a native English speaker.

Comment: Have you checked a [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reciprocate)? If you're still puzzled, let us know why. And you're probably going to have to give us a sentence or two before that unusual statement for us to make sense of it: *reciprocate* involves responding to a previous action.

Comment: It makes no sense at all. As you say *reciprocate* means to invert in some way .e.g. *I invited him to dinner and he reciprocated by inviting me to his place*. Your example sounds like a malapropism. I wonder what they could have meant?

Comment: It might be an attempt at 'mirrored' in the sense of 'echoed' (her belt was sparkling with glitter, glitter reciprocated in my bag) but you really need to give the complete sentence, and possibly the previous one.

Comment: I can only imagine this makes sense if previously there was a statement about what something in the bag did to the bag's other occupants.

Comment: You should probably provide us with some actual context.

Comment: @WS2 - "Reciprocate" means to go back and forth, not "invert".

Answer (score 1):

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reciprocate

> : to do (something) for or to someone who has done something similar
>   for or to you
>
> : to have (a feeling) for someone who has the same feeling for you
>
> : to move back and forth again and again

I would guess that the author meant that the glitter in fact "glittered", but was at a loss for a synonym for "glittered" to avoid the circularity.  ("Sparkled" is what a brief search comes up with, but that word kind of lacks sparkle.)

Comment: The OED lists eleven different senses. The backward-forward motion is limited to meanings connected to mechanical engineering.

Comment: I believe you've seized the elusive beast by the throat, +1 @Hot Licks. Without knowing more I believe it to be a poetic (rather than literal) statement, made for literary effect.

Answer (score 0):

*Reciprocate*, sense 2: "to move or cause to move backwards and forwards" (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reciprocate).

I have only ever seen this usage in connexion with steam engines, and I certainly wouldn't recommend it to anyone not both a native English speaker and trying for an effect.

Comment: You've never heard of a *reciprocating* saw??  And Wankle rotary gasoline engine is the "opposite" of the standard *reciprocating* gasoline engine.

Comment: This is a standard term in aviation: [Pilot's Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/pilot_handbook/media/PHAK%20-%20Chapter%2006.pdf): *Reciprocating engines and turboprop engines
work in combination with a propeller to produce thrust.
Turbojet and turbofan engines produce thrust by increasing
the velocity of air flowing through the engine*